# const void * vs. void const *

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I am getting different answers for this question. I know that the order for other data types doesn't matter/simply by preference (e.g. const char * and char const *).

Not sure if the same applies to void *:
const void * == void const *?

Comment: No, there's no difference. `void` acts just like any other data type syntactically.

Comment: `const void *` is a pointer to an unknown object that is constant. `void const *` is a pointer to a constant unknown object. Semantically exactly the same. In this context `void` behaves as any other type.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. `const void *ptr` and `void const *ptr` define the object `ptr` having the type of `pointer to const void`.

If you move the const beyond the `*` it will change the meaning of the definition.

```
void * const ptr;
```

Will define `ptr` as `const pointer to void`.

All together:

```
const void *ptr;   // <= pointer to const void
void const *ptr;   // <= pointer to const void
void * const ptr;  // <= const pointer to void
const void * const ptr; // <= const pointer to const void
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between `void` and any other type in this case -- both declarations create a pointer to a `const void`.

It's a bit weird and redundant since a `void` expression cannot be the target of an assignment anyway; the compiler would bitch if the dereferenced pointer was the target of an assignment whether it was declared `const` or not.  IOW,

```
void *ptr;
...
*ptr = some_T_value; // constraint violation, target is void
```

You'd have to cast `ptr` to point to a different, non-array object type to do the assignment:

```
*(T *)ptr = some_T_value;
```

Declaring `ptr` as `const void *` doesn't really buy you anything.

Now, if you had done something like

```
void * const ptr;
```

this *would* be different; instead of creating a pointer to a `const void`, you're creating a `const` pointer to `void`; you wouldn't be able to assign to `*ptr` because it's a `void` expression, but you wouldn't be able to assign to `ptr` either, since *it's* declared `const` in this case.

Comment: Re “Declaring `ptr` as `const void *` doesn't really buy you anything”: After `const void *p;`, `int *i = p;` produces a diagnostic. After `void *p;`, it does not.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Ah.  Interesting.  Didn't think about that (obviously)